# c++ - binding operator= member of std::string

Tags: c++, functor

I have a class (let's call it `myclass`). One of its private member variables is a `std::function` called `myfunctor` of return type `bool` and that takes two arguments:

```
bool
myfunction
    (const std::string & input, std::string & output)
{
    output = input;
}
```

The constructor of `myclass` shall receive a reference to the output `std::string` as its only parameter, so that the way to initialize it would be something like this:

```
myclass::myclass
    (std::string & s)
: myfunctor( std::bind(myfunction, std::placeholders::_1, s) )
{
    return;
}
```

I was hoping, however, that there's a way to **directly use `operator=`** from `std::string`. But I have still not found it. I've tried with many different combinations without luck:

`std::bind( (std::string & (std::string::*) (std::string &)) &(s.operator=), placeholders::_1`

and so on, but compiler (GCC 4.8.0) gave me errors like `no matches converting to ...`.

Comment: Did you intend `=` to be `==`?

Comment: I think you'll have to specify the overload, as there are several overloads of `std::string::operator=`. But are you aware storing a reference in `bind` may leave a dangling reference if the object passed to `myclass::myclass` has been destroyed?

Comment: @BoPersson No, I meant `=`. I want to assign, not to compare.
@DyP How? I've tried several ways but the compiler still complains about unresolvable overloads.

Comment: Why not just use a lambda?  It's so much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast in order to specify the overload of `std::string::operator=` you want to use (there is more than one). Additionally, you need the object this **member function** acts upon (= the `this` pointer used within the member function).

Or, if you really need to return a bool, you could wrap the call in a lambda:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::string mystring;
    std::function<bool(std::string const&)> f =
      [&mystring](std::string const& rhs)->bool { mystring = rhs; return true; };

    f("hello world");

    std::cout << mystring << std::endl;
}
```

---

Version with explicit overload resolution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    // nice C++11 syntax
    using assignment_FPT = std::string& (std::string::*)(std::string const&);
    // in case your compiler doesn't know that yet
    //typedef std::string& (std::string::*assignment_FPT)(std::string const&);

    std::string mystring;
    auto f = std::bind(
      static_cast<assignment_FPT>(&std::string::operator=),
      std::ref(mystring),  // either `ref` or a pointer (or it will be copied)
      std::placeholders::_1);

    f("hello world");

    std::cout << mystring << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It keeps complaining. Remember that my `std::function` has to be `std::function<bool(const std::string &)>`. Putting what you've posted makes GCC say `no matching function for call to ...`.
- Ok, sorry, I've just realized that `std::string::operator=` does not return `bool` and it would be pretty difficult to make a workaround about that, so I should keep going on with a wrapper.

Comment: Why does your function return bool? What should be returned? `std::string::operator=` returns `*this`, that is, the string on the left side of the assignment `lhs = rhs`.

Comment: @Kalrish You can have another level of indirection (another call to `bind`) to convert `std::string` to `bool`, but what's that good for? What do you return, always `true`?

Comment: The function is meant to be some kind of translator. This would be the  simplest one (no translation being done), but I could implement another that mapped, let's say, strings with boolean values (i.e. `true`, `false`, and so on). By returning `true` or `false`, the "translator" function shall tell the caller if the translation could be done or not (for example, I expect `on` or `off` and I receive `foobar`; that would return `false`).

Comment: Why modify your lambda behavior with `std::bind`, when you can just use the right lambda in the first place? `[&mystring](std::string const& rhs) -> bool { mystring = rhs; return true; };`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley +1 Because it evolved from the second example to the first example. I just basically changed it to that :)

Comment: Thanks, @BenjaminLindley, DyP (it does not let me to notify both of you... not sure how does it work). This worked like a charm. I knew a bit about lambdas, but not enough (I have just realized...). Thanks a lot, I'm reading about lambdas right now.